# Enable UWP ListView virtualization in nested controls

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, listview, uwp

I have the following `ScrollViewer` with a `StackPanel` inside it:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1"
              x:Name="testScroll">
    <StackPanel
        x:Name="LezioniPopupStackPanel">
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

and from code, I need to populate the stackpanel with Expanders that have a custom UserControl inside, based on dynamic data that I get from an API.
The custom usercontrol has a single ListView in it.

The UserControl:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="ClassevivaPCTO.Controls.LessonsListView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ClassevivaPCTO.Controls"
    xmlns:adapters="using:ClassevivaPCTO.Adapters"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:converters="using:ClassevivaPCTO.Converters"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

//LessonListViewDataTemplate template redacted for simplicity

    <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LessonListViewDataTemplate}" 
              />
</UserControl>
```

The code to add the listviews to an `Expander`, then to the `stackpanel`, after getting some data from an API:

```
...
//add an expander control for every subject
foreach (var currentSubject in subjects.Subjects)
{
    //list of lessons for the current subject id
    var subjectLessons = lessons.Lessons
        .Where(lesson => lesson.subjectId == currentSubject.id)
        .ToList();

    //run on ui thread
    await CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(
        CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
        async () =>
        {
            var expander = new Expander
            {
                Header = currentSubject.description,
            };

            var listviewlessons = new LessonsListView() { ItemsSource = subjectLessons, };

            expander.Content = listviewlessons;

            LezioniPopupStackPanel.Children.Add(expander);
        }
    );
}
```

The problem is that when loading the data the UI hangs for almost 10 seconds just by adding the listviews to the expanders.
I guessed the problem was that virtualization was not enabled, so I tried to set the listviews' height to 100, and in fact the data loaded in under 1 second.

I need the listviews' height to be infinite, but how can i enable virtualization given that the listviews are inside an expander?

Comment: List View uses [UI virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/optimize-gridview-and-listview#ui-virtualization) by default. The problem doesn't seem to be related to UI Virtualization. How much data does your ListView have in total? How your UserControl `LessonsListView` is used?

Comment: I have ~200 items/listview for 10 expanders. `How your UserControl LessonsListView is used?` What do you mean? In the question i posted the code I use to initialize the usercontrol

Comment: I did a simple test without using ItemTemplate, just a list of strings, and it ran smoothly. It may be that you have too much data, can the same problem be reproduced after setting 20 items/listview for 10 expanders. or you can provide a [mcve] to help us further check the problem for you?

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT Okay, I created a simple app that has the same UI freeze problem here: https://github.com/Gabboxl/ExpanderDemo

Comment: Have you checked my newest reply?

Answer (score 0):

You add too many UI elements at one time, causing the UI thread block, so it is better to load the UI elements separately. You can refer to the following code to use the [Expander.Expanded Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.controls.expander.expanded?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.0) to load the listview when the Expander control is expanded for the first time.

```
private void TestButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //generate 10 random school subjects
    var subjects = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var subject = "Subject " + i;
        subjects.Add(subject);
    }

    foreach (var subject in subjects)
    {
        var expander = new Expander();
        expander.Header = subject;
        expander.Expanded += Expander_Expanded;
        TestStackPanel.Children.Add(expander);                          
    }

}

private void Expander_Expanded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Expander expander = sender as Expander;
    if (expander.Content != null)
        return;

    var lessons = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 250; i++)
    {
        var lesson = "Lesson " + i;
        lessons.Add(lesson);
    }

    var listView = new ListView();
    listView.ItemsSource = lessons;
    expander.Content = listView;
}
```